# Preventing `TeX-command-run-all` from shifting focus

Tags: auctex, pdf-tools, focus

It seems that `TeX-command-run-all` shifts focus to the pdf window, which is  quite annoying.  Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I think that this is not the standard behaviour with pdf-tools. At least on my system with emacs 27.0.5, latest AUCTeX and pdf-tools from melpa, the focus is kept in the window with the tex file. I have tested it with emacs -Q and minimal config.

Answer (score 1):

I use `xdotool` to shift focus back to Emacs after `Tex-command-run-all`. Works on an X system (Linux/Unix) with `xdotool` installed. I use `Okular` as `pdf-viewer` and the following settings:

```
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Okular")))

(setq TeX-view-program-list 
'(("Okular" "emacswinno=`xdotool getwindowfocus` \; okular --unique %o\#src:%n`pwd`/./%b \; sleep 0.1\; xdotool windowactivate $emacswinno")))
```

The xdotool solution will work with any pdf viewer, but it is actually an overkill if you use Okular. I just realized you can call Okular with the option `--noraise` to prevent it from taking focus. So if you use Okular, the following setting will work:

```
(setq TeX-view-program-list
  '(("Okular" ("okular --noraise --unique %o"  (mode-io-correlate "#src:%n%a")) "okular")))
```

Comment: If that is necessary, I feel there is something wrong with AUCTeX.

Comment: There is a user option: TeX-view-evince-keep-focus

When this option is non-nil and the viewer is compatible with evince, the focus is pulled back to Emacs immediately after the viewer is invoked or refreshed from within AUCTeX. from here https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Starting-Viewers.html This option as well as xdotools should not affect pdf-tools.

Comment: The option `TeX-view-evince-keep-focus` doesn't work with Okular unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

does

```
(add-hook 'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions
        #'TeX-revert-document-buffer))
```

do the trick ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. It turned out that adding the `-g` option to the Skim command invoked in `TeX-view-program-list` solved it for me for Skim+MacOS. Maybe there are similar options for other PDF viewers.

```lisp
;; DOOM-EMACS snippet
(after! tex
  :config
  (dolist (viewer (reverse +latex-viewers))
  (pcase viewer
    (`skim
     (when-let
         (app-path
          (and IS-MAC
               (file-exists-p! (or "/Applications/Skim.app"
                                   "~/Applications/Skim.app"))))
       (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection '(output-pdf "Skim"))
       (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list
                    (list "Skim" (format "%s/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -r -b -g %%n %%o %%b"
                                         app-path)))))))
  )
```

Note: I edited the code from https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/master/modules/lang/latex/%2Bviewers.el to ensure that it only affects Skim if Skim was selected in the doom config.